# Snowflake - Give full access on database to role; revoke access on specific schemas to user that is part of the role

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to do this?
There is a admin role which is the owner of the database, schema & all other objects.
There is tester role with only read/write permissions on 1 schema of the database.
The tester role needs to be a part of the admin role for that 1 specific schema (so that any new objects created - the ownership will be on the admin role).
Have to revoke access to users of the tester role access on all other schemas in the database

I've tried these scripts:

```
grant role testerrole to user tester1;

grant usage on database DEMODB to role adminrole;
grant usage on database DEMODB to role testerrole;
grant all on database DEMODB to role adminrole;
grant select,insert,update,delete in schema "DEMODB"."DEVSCHM" to role testerrole;

--Adding tester role in admin role
grant role adminrole to testerrole;

-- revoke all other schema access to tester1 (This fails. How to fix this?)
revoke usage on schema "DEMODB"."PRDSCHM" from user tester1;
revoke usage on schema "DEMODB"."QASSCHM" from user tester1;
```

Looking to accomplish this - The testerrole needs to be able to create objects in the DEVSCHM, but ownership of the object should still be held with adminrole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question, you want the admin role to own all objects regardless of the role that created them. If that is the case then just grant future ownership on the relevant objects to the admin role